# Slider Revolution Full Screen Too Large

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I am in the process of building a Wordpress theme and I am using Slider Revolution on the home page. For some reason when I set the slider to full screen background the height is much larger than 100vh. Like 10000px or something. This issue only occurs with my theme. When I activate the Twenty Nineteen or Twenty Seventeen theme the slider displays correctly. The site is currently hosted at [ohmsandbox.com](http://ohmsandbox.com).

Also, I am using the Elementor page builder plugin. My understanding is that the header.php and footer.php files are loaded and the rest of the page is using Elementor. I can provide login credentials if someone is interested in looking at the theme files.

Comment: Did you try a premade slider revolution template?

Comment: I haven't tried a premade slider. I'm hoping to not use a premade slider and use my own.

Comment: You can try premade, and adjust other elements as your need.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding `<!doctype html>` to my header.php file.